# Android Camera Intent calling onCreate again

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application that calls the Camera, takes picture and create a thumbnail. It was working perfectly until now...I don't know for what reason, but now when I takes the picture and click on "Save" (android's default) the onCreate method is called.

So, the load of my thumbnail is not working anymore

I already tried to modify my Android manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

onCreate is still called.

Method to take picture:

```
public void takePicture() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper(this);
    fileUri = fileHelper.saveFile();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, ConstantsHelper.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Is there any way to prevent that the "onCreate" is called after taking a picture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. You just need to fix your code such that it works across the natural Activity lifecycle. Whether or not your previous Activity instance will stay alive when another comes to the foreground just depends on the device (how much memory is available to your app, whether "Don't Keep Activities" is checked under Developer Options, etc.)

It's a case that is perfectly valid, and expected to happen on the platform, and your Activity should be able to handle saving and restoring its state properly if it's killed off.

Whatever state you're initializing in `onCreate()`, just make sure you retain it in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and when `onCreate()` happens again, check if `savedInstanceState` is non-null. If it's not, restore whatever state you saved and continue on.

Comment: Hi! Your comment made to remember that I checked the developer options, to "not keep activities"...I have to develop the savedInstance anyway?

Comment: The "Don't Keep Activities" option is basically a setting you can enable to trigger what will happen naturally in memory constrained environments. So it's likely that *most* of the time, with that setting unchecked, your activity won't be killed. However, there's no guarantee, and you'll definitely have some crashes out in the field if you don't handle that case.